# How to set a TV banner in Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, ember.js, android-tv

**I don't know how to set the TV banner in Cordova, so the installed app uses it on the home screen.**

I'm using [`cordova-plugin-android-tv`](https://github.com/frontyard/cordova-plugin-android-tv) which adds `android:banner="@drawable/banner"` to the `<application>` element as explain on the documentation:

https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start#banner

This is performed at [`cordova/plugins/cordova-plugin-android-tv/patch.js`](https://github.com/frontyard/cordova-plugin-android-tv/blob/master/patch.js).

Installing the plugin worked at once and also the TV support. I was able to install the app in an Android TV and there is a launch banner on the home screen. But it's not the banner I've indicated.

The problem is that I don't know how to include the TV banner in Cordova.

I've tried putting it at `cordova/res/drawable-xhdpi/banner.png` and also at `cordova/res/drawable/banner.png`.

In `config.xml` I've included:

```
<platform name="android">
  <resource-file 
    src="res/drawable-xhdpi/banner.png" 
    target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/banner.png" />
</platform>
```

And also have tried:

```
<platform name="android">
  <resource-file 
    src="res/drawable/banner.png" 
    target="app/src/main/res/drawable/banner.png" />
</platform>
```

**But I don't see the banner in the Android TV home screen when it's installed.**

**How is it to be done?**

I've checked Android and Cordova documentation, but I don't figure out how to achieve it:

https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start#banner

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#BitmapFile

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/8.x/config_ref/index.html#resource-file

I'm developing the Cordova app with an [Ember.js](https://emberjs.com/) aplication using the [Corber plugin](http://corber.io/). The version is Cordova 8.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Use a "splash" element in the `platform name=android` in your cordova *config.xml*. Android build will copy your images into `YOUR_CORDOVA_PROJECT/platforms/android/app/ src/main/res/drawable`.

**Sizes are:**

- land-ldpi: 320x200px
- land-mdpi: 480x320px
- land-hdpi: 800x480px
- land-xhdpi: 1280x720px
- land-xxhdpi: 1600x960px
- land-xxxhdpi: 1920x1280px
- port-ldpi: 200x320px
- port-mdpi: 320x480px
- port-hdpi: 480x800px
- port-xhdpi: 720x1280px
- port-xxhdpi: 960x1600px
- port-xxxhdpi: 1280x1920px

**config.xml:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="sk.otta.android" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"     xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>...</name>
<description>...</description>
<author email="..." href="...">...</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="PATH_TO_IMAGE" />
    <icon density="ldpi" src="PATH_TO_IMAGEg" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="PATH_TO_IMAGE" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="PATH_TO_IMAGE" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="PATH_TO_IMAGE" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="PATH_TO_IMAGE" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="PATH_TO_BANNER" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="PATH_TO_BANNER" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="PATH_TO_BANNER" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="PATH_TO_BANNER" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="PATH_TO_BANNER" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="PATH_TO_BANNER" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="PATH_TO_BANNER" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="PATH_TO_BANNER" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="PATH_TO_BANNER" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="PATH_TO_BANNER" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src=PATH_TO_BANNER" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="PATH_TO_BANNER" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
```

Hope it helps! :)